# Custom Calculation Based on Pivot Table Data

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that returns the following data:

`Accounting_Code` - `(Values are 12345, 23456, 45678)`

`Users` - `(Values are User 1, User 2, USer 3)`

`Total_Time` - `(Values are Hours logged per accounting code per user)`

I would like to create two custom fields based on the accounting code.
The first is to create a field called 'Core' which calculates based on the value of 12345 from the Accountg field.  The second is called 'Other' and calculates values based on items that are anything other than 'Core'.

My intent is to capture the % of time people are spending between Core and Other.

I am struggling coming up with the formula to get this data based on the value of a field.
Can someone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Calculated Item function within pivot tables.

First let's say this is your data.

```
AccCode UserID  TotalTime
12345   1   02:00
12345   2   04:00
12345   3   03:00
23456   1   03:00
23456   2   01:00
23456   3   01:00
34567   1   04:00
34567   2   02:00
34567   3   01:00
```

Create a simple pivot table that looks like this:

```
AccCode Sum of TotalTime
12345   09:00:00
23456   05:00:00
34567   07:00:00
Grand Total 21:00:00
```

Now, click on your pivot table, selecting the cell containing 12345. Click the **PivotTable Tools** ribbon, and then the **Fields, Items & Sets** button (within the Calculation area). Pick **Calculated Item**.

First your Core item. Set the Name of your Calculated Item to 'Core' and double-click 12345 in the items section. Click **Add** to insert the new line to your pivot table.

Repeat for 'Other', but this time the formula will be ='23456'+'34567'.

Filter the rows for your pivot table to only show 'Core' and 'Other', and then right click the Sum of TotalTime column, hover over **Show Values As**, and pick **% of Grand Total**.